# XMPP/facebook chat connection for android

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, chat

```
public class ClientJabberActivity extends Activity {

private final static String SERVER_HOST = "chat.facebook.com";
private final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
private final static String SERVICE_NAME = "chat.facebook.com"; 
private final static String LOGIN = "xxxxx@chat.facebook.com";
private final static String PASSWORD = "xxxxxx";


private List<String> m_discussionThread;
private ArrayAdapter<String> m_discussionThreadAdapter;
private XMPPConnection m_connection;
private Handler m_handler;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    m_handler = new Handler();
    try {
        initConnection();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final EditText recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
    final EditText message = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.message);        
    ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.thread);

    m_discussionThread = new ArrayList<String>();
    m_discussionThreadAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.multi_line_list_item, m_discussionThread);
    list.setAdapter(m_discussionThreadAdapter);

    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String to = recipient.getText().toString();
            String text = message.getText().toString();

            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);
            m_connection.sendPacket(msg);
            m_discussionThread.add("moi :");
            m_discussionThread.add(text);
            m_discussionThreadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}


private void initConnection() throws XMPPException {
    //Initialisation de la connexion
    ConnectionConfiguration config =
            new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
    m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    m_connection.connect();
    m_connection.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD);
    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
    m_connection.sendPacket(presence);

    //enregistrement de l'écouteur de messages
    PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
    m_connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    m_discussionThread.add(fromName + ":");
                    m_discussionThread.add(message.getBody());

                    m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            m_discussionThreadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);
}

}
```

this code i used to make connection with facebook chat, but the connection can not be established i don't know why . it works well with gmail

```
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:665)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at com.developpez.florentgarin.android.ClientJabberActivity$1.onClick(ClientJabberActivity.java:61)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-18 16:06:20.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 16:06:43.167: ERROR/installd(35): eof
02-18 16:06:43.167: ERROR/installd(35): failed to read size
02-18 16:07:11.857: ERROR/Zygote(470): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
02-18 16:07:16.408: ERROR/BatteryService(477): usbOnlinePath not found
02-18 16:07:16.408: ERROR/BatteryService(477): batteryVoltagePath not found
02-18 16:07:16.408: ERROR/BatteryService(477): batteryTemperaturePath not found
02-18 16:07:16.477: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(477): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
02-18 16:07:16.758: ERROR/SensorService(477): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
```

Comment: Are there any log messages telling what the server response is?

Comment: sometimes the connection is opened after that an excption is raised says that not connected to the server ,,

Comment: Please refer this link.. There is good answer for facebook chat connection for android and it is worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
private final static String LOGIN = "xxxxx@chat.facebook.com";
```

To:

```
private final static String LOGIN = "xxxxx";
```

Well not exactly ;). You get the idea though..

XMPP spec for facebook does not include the @server.here for login. Either include it in your username string or delete your server string entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook login is different:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

import de.measite.smack.Sasl;

public class FacebookConnectSASLMechanism  extends SASLMechanism
{

    private String sessionKey = "";
    private String sessionSecret = "";
    private String apiKey = "";

    public FacebookConnectSASLMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
            super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    // protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
    // String[] mechanisms = { getName() };
    // Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", hostname, props,
    // this);
    //
    // super.authenticate();
    // }

    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
            StringBuilder stanza = new StringBuilder();
            stanza.append("<auth mechanism=\"").append(getName());
            stanza.append("\" xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\">");
            stanza.append("</auth>");

            // Send the authentication to the server
            //getSASLAuthentication().send(stanza.toString());
    }

    public void authenticate(String apiKeyAndSessionKey, String host, String sessionSecret)
                    throws IOException, XMPPException {

            if(apiKeyAndSessionKey==null || sessionSecret==null)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid parameters!");

            String[] keyArray = apiKeyAndSessionKey.split("\\|");

            if(keyArray==null || keyArray.length != 2)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Api key or session key is not present!");

            this.apiKey = keyArray[0];
            this.sessionKey = keyArray[1];
            this.sessionSecret = sessionSecret;

            this.authenticationId = sessionKey;
            this.password = sessionSecret;
            this.hostname = host;

            String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
            Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
            sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
            authenticate();
    }

    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh)
                    throws IOException, XMPPException {
            String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
            Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
            sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, cbh);
            authenticate();
    }

    protected String getName() {
            return "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";
    }

    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
            // Build the challenge response stanza encoding the response text
            StringBuilder stanza = new StringBuilder();

            byte response[] = null;
            if (challenge != null) {
                    String decodedResponse = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
                    Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedResponse);

                    String version = "1.0";
                    String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
                    String method = parameters.get("method");

                    Long callId = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()/1000;

                    String sig = "api_key="+apiKey
                                                    +"call_id="+callId
                                                    +"method="+method
                                                    +"nonce="+nonce
                                                    +"session_key="+sessionKey
                                                    +"v="+version
                                                    +sessionSecret;

                    try {
                            sig = MD5(sig);
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }

                    String composedResponse = "api_key="+apiKey+"&"
                                                                            +"call_id="+callId+"&"
                                                                            +"method="+method+"&"
                                                                            +"nonce="+nonce+"&"
                                                                            +"session_key="+sessionKey+"&"
                                                                            +"v="+version+"&"
                                                                            +"sig="+sig;

                    response = composedResponse.getBytes();
            }

            String authenticationText="";

            if (response != null) {
                    authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response, Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
            }

            stanza.append("<response xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\">");
            stanza.append(authenticationText);
            stanza.append("</response>");

            // Send the authentication to the server
            //getSASLAuthentication().send(stanza);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
            String[] params = query.split("&");
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (String param : params) {
                    String name = param.split("=")[0];
                    String value = param.split("=")[1];
                    map.put(name, value);
            }
            return map;
    }

private String convertToHex(byte[] data) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
        int two_halfs = 0;
        do {
            if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9))
                buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
            else
                buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
            halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
        } while(two_halfs++ < 1);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

public String MD5(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException  {
    MessageDigest md;
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] md5hash = new byte[32];
    md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
    md5hash = md.digest();
    return convertToHex(md5hash);
}
}
```

Comment: hi Raj..how do i implement SaslClient..i dont have any idea regarding this...if u please help me in this coz i m not abble to connect facebook chat with XMPP..