# Integrate Facebook chat in android with Asmack API

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat, asmack

I try to implement chat support as suggested in [this blog](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/).

Currently, I'm using following code to implement chatting interface.

***Java Code***

**TestChatActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TestChatActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private EditText mRecipient;
private EditText mSendText;
private ListView mList;
private XMPPConnection mConnection;
private String mHost, mPort, mService, mUsername, mPassword;
private ConnectionConfiguration mConnConfig;
private String TAG;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initLayout();
    // initGtalk();
    initFB();

    // Create a connection
    createConnection();

    // login
    loginToXMPP();

}

void initLayout() {
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "onCreate called");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mRecipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mRecipient = " + mRecipient);
    mSendText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sendText);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mSendText = " + mSendText);
    mList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mList = " + mList);
    // Set a listener to send a chat text message
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);

    setListAdapter();
}

void initGtalk() {
    mHost = "talk.google.com";
    mPort = "5222";
    mService = "gmail";
    mUsername = "abc@gmail.com";
    mPassword = "password";
    // Set Default recipients for Gtalk
    mRecipient.setText("default_buddy@gmail.com");
}

void initFB() {
    mHost = "chat.facebook.com";
    mPort = "5222";
    mService = "xmpp";
    mUsername = "userid@chat.facebook.com";
    mPassword = "password";
    // Set Default recipients for FB
    mRecipient.setText("new_userid@chat.facebook.com");
}

void createConnection() {
    mConnConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(mHost,
            Integer.parseInt(mPort), mService);
    mConnConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
    mConnConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    mConnection = new XMPPConnection(mConnConfig);

    try {
        mConnection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + mConnection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "
                + mConnection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
}

void loginToXMPP() {
    try {
        mConnection.login(mUsername, mPassword);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + mConnection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        mConnection.sendPacket(presence);
        setConnection(mConnection);
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as "
                + mUsername);
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
}

/**
 * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is established with the XMPP
 * server
 * 
 * @param connection
 */
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
    this.mConnection = connection;
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody()
                            + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                    messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    messages.add(message.getBody());
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}

private void setListAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.multi_line_list_item, messages);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.send) {
        String to = mRecipient.getText().toString();
        String text = mSendText.getText().toString();

        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");
        Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
        msg.setBody(text);
        mConnection.sendPacket(msg);
        messages.add(mConnection.getUser() + ":");
        messages.add(text);
        setListAdapter();
    }

}
}
```

**Layouts**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="70dp"
        android:text="Recipient:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/recipient"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:minWidth="250dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listMessages"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sendText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:capitalize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send" >
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

**multi_line_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="false"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Above code uses **Asmack** Library

Google Talk work fine for me but Facebook chat not worked with this code. :(

Is there any special configuration used for Facebook chat connectivity? Or this method wrong to connect with Facebook chat?

Because I’ve done many R&D on that and Facebook support XMPP chat support as discussed in [Facebook XMPP chat Settings](https://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php) so, As I ‘am thinking this should be work.

Anybody have implemented Facebook chat in android can help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Same problem for me also, i'm also searching for solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked all code of [Beem Project](http://beem-project.com/) and found the solution for connecting with Facebook chat API.

**Steps for implementing Facebook chat API in Android:**

1. First we have to implement [MemorizingTrustManager](https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager) Library project in existing project.

   => For that you have to copy following three files in existing project

   - MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MTMDecision.java
   - MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MemorizingActivity.java
   - MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MemorizingTrustManager.java

   => And add following values in **values/string.xml**

   ```
   <resources>
       <string name="mtm_accept_cert">Accept Unknown Certificate?</string>
       <string name="mtm_decision_always">Always</string>
       <string name="mtm_decision_once">Once</string>
       <string name="mtm_decision_abort">Abort</string>
       <string name="mtm_notification">Certificate Verification</string>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Second step, Instead of using **SASLAuthentication** such as **X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM**, You can used following code to connect with Facebook and login using your **Facebook Jabber ID (username@chat.facebook.com)**

   ```
   public void connectToFb() throws XMPPException {

   ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
   config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
   config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
   config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
   config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
   config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
   config.setTruststoreType("bks");
   config.setSendPresence(false);
   try {
       SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
       sc.init(null, MemorizingTrustManager.getInstanceList(this), new java.security.SecureRandom());
       config.setCustomSSLContext(sc);
   } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
       Log.w("TAG", "Unable to use MemorizingTrustManager", e);
   }
   XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
   try {
       xmpp.connect();
       xmpp.login("facebookusername", "****"); // Here you have to used only facebookusername from facebookusername@chat.facebook.com
       Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
       Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
       System.out.println("Connected!");
       System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
       // shows first time onliners---->
       String temp[] = new String[50];
       int i = 0;
       for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
           String user = entry.getUser();
           Log.i("TAG", user);
       }
   } catch (XMPPException e) {
       xmpp.disconnect();
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```

At last, If you get all the Buddy list of your Facebook account in LogCat View, than you can implement simple Facebook chat using [this tutorial](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/).

**UPDATE** : I'm also working on sample app that work as Facebook Messenger and posted on GitHub soon.

Comment: hi Hitesh Patel. Can you please give me a link to download the jar to import XMPP and ConnectionConfiguration in my android project to implement FB chat.

Comment: @Hitesh Patel Hello, have you done it? Please provide the link for GitHub repository of this project, if uploaded. Thank you

Comment: Hi Hitesh, I'm getting `trust anchor for certification path not found` error.

Comment: "For that you have to copy following three files in existing project", to where copy them????