# How to create Multiple XMPP client's for Chatting?

Tags: android, xmpp

How do I create a XMPP chat client in Android for Yahoo, AOL, and Hotmail (MSN).
Right now i was created for Gtalk and Facebook by using `smack` library..

i want to create for Yahoo, AOL, Hotmail, like eBuddy application.

looking for `server_name` and `port number` for AOL, Yahoo, Hotmail.

I searched a lot for AOL i got this

```
SERVER_HOST = "xmpp.oscar.aol.com"; 
SERVER_PORT = 5222;
```

but no luck..Can anyone suggest some detailed information regarding this SERVER_HOST , SERVER_PORT.

Comment: Can any one help me on this requirement...

Comment: Would you mind posting how you were able to do this for facebook? I have been trying but have been unsuccessful. I'm investigating AOL and Yahoo now and I will post an answer when I figure out how to.

Comment: @Peter look at this Question and Answer we will get a solution for facebook chat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook

Comment: Are you recommending the accepted answer?

Comment: yes it has full code, check it for your requirement, if you are un-clear about that let me know.

Answer (score 2):

For Google Talk and Facebook you can connect with standard XMPP client. Connect to talk.google.com/chat.facebook.com as host and use your gmail address/username@chat.facebook.com as Jabber ID.

To connect directly to MSN via XMPP you need to implement their proprietary X-MESSENGER-OAUTH2 authentication mechanism, as described at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826554.aspx). There are code samples out for smack [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826553.aspx).

For AIM and Yahoo I think you can only connect to via another XMPP server with a corresponding transport installed, like [pyYIMt](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/yahoo/) or [PyAIMt](http://code.google.com/p/pyaimt/).

Comment: pyYIMt and PyAIMt these are not related to android, there is no .java files.

Comment: See this as a reference, its a public questions and others might be iterested in how you did that. Regarding those transports: Yes this are server extensions, they connect to a local server. You cant connect to those services directly if they do not support XMPP.

Comment: in eBuddy application those are not using any Authentications for MSN client. just they are talking username and password like gtalk. and for AIM And Yahoo no use of your shared links there is no information about Serverhost ans portnumbers..

Comment: Life is no picnic. AIM "experimented" with XMPP back in 2008. Since they changed owners, that has no meaning for today. Yahoo has their own API. Maybe they will release a XMPP API in the future. So your question does not make it exist, unfortunately.

Comment: actually i raised this question because of i did't fine server_name and port_number for AIM, Hotmail and Yahoo. but i did't get those values here. mainly requires information regarding this SERVER_HOST , SERVER_PORT. i was worked on Gtalk and Facebook using smack those are working fine. struggling for remaining clients .