# Sending private message with facebook api?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

Okay i really researched a lot the internet for revealing is it possible or not.
And i found various answers, both yes, and no - thus, i couldnt find a decent example or tutorial.

I searched in facebook developers webpage, and [only found mailbox api](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/08/11/new-opportunities-for-inbox-and-notification-integration/) that only letting you know you have some  inbox messages, but you cannot send any, but that facebook developer blog post is from 2009 so maybe they have changed some things.

So please if anybody knows some reliable information about whether i can or cannot:
Send private messages from my native application through facebook api to one of my friend/friends?

And Yes, i know there are a lot of similiar questions like this on stackoverflow but what the hell, i need some up-to-date info.

**E D I T:**

Well i found [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartancoders.gtok&hl=en) that can do the tricks.
But there is no official facebook blog about how to do this? I cant belive this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send private messages with the current Facebook API. I'm guessing they removed it because of spambots etc.

Comment: A, thought you had an app that wanted to send "requests" via chat, a chat application between users should be possible, but they haven't seem to created an API for android, I found these: [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook)

Comment: So i need a chat server for this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: So we can't send any message to the friends using the sdk anymore?