# Can't log in Facebook Chat via XMPP on Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, xmpp, chat

I've wrote a Android in App in which I want to Integrate a Chat via XMPP.
I've logged in Facebook with permission for XMPPLogin. But when I want to login in Facebook from XMPP I receive this XML Response:

```
RCV  (1095775528): <failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/></failure></stream:stream>
```

causing this Error:

```
SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM: 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:341)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:242)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:371)
at com.example.messenger.ChatActivity.testLogin(ChatActivity.java:240)
at com.example.messenger.ChatActivity.access$0(ChatActivity.java:189)
at com.example.messenger.ChatActivity$1$1.run(ChatActivity.java:70)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is how I use the Login

```
private void testLogin(){

        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222, "chat.facebook.com");
        Log.i("XMPP Client", "ConnectionConfig");
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
       config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        Log.i("XMPP Client", "config Complete");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
            config.setTruststorePassword(null);
            config.setTruststorePath(null);

        } else {
            config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
            String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
            if (path == null)
                path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                                                + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                                                + "cacerts.bks";
            config.setTruststorePath(path);
        }

        Log.i("XMPP Client", "config if else complete");
        xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);

        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);

        Log.i("XMPP Client", "new Connection and sasl auth done");
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient","Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            Log.i("XMPPClient","Unable to " + xmpp.getHost());

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("XMPP Client", "xmpp connect done");
        try {


            String apiKey = Session.getActiveSession().getApplicationId();
            String sessionKey = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();

            String sessionSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            Log.i("XMPP Client", Session.getActiveSession().getApplicationId());
            xmpp.login(apiKey + "|" + sessionKey, sessionSecret , "Messenger");


            Log.i("XMPPClient"," its logined ");

            Log.i("Connected",""+xmpp.isConnected());

            if ( xmpp.isConnected()){
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                xmpp.sendPacket(presence);

            }

        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

and this is my SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism  Class

```
package com.example.messenger;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism
{

    private static final String NAME              = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

    private String              apiKey            = "";
    private String              applicationSecret = "";
    private String              sessionKey        = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication)
    {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException
    {

        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String apiKeyAndSessionKey, String host,
            String applicationSecret) throws IOException, XMPPException
    {
        if (apiKeyAndSessionKey == null || applicationSecret == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
        }

        String[] keyArray = apiKeyAndSessionKey.split("\\|", 2);
        if (keyArray.length < 2)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "API key or session key is not present");
        }

        this.apiKey = keyArray[0];
        this.applicationSecret = applicationSecret;
        this.sessionKey = keyArray[1];

        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc =
                Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props,
                        this);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh)
            throws IOException, XMPPException
    {
        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc =
                Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props,
                        cbh);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName()
    {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] response = null;

        if (challenge != null)
        {
            String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
            Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

            String version = "1.0";
            String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
            String method = parameters.get("method");

            long callId = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();

            String sig =
                    "api_key=" + apiKey + "call_id=" + callId + "method="
                            + method + "nonce=" + nonce + "session_key="
                            + sessionKey + "v=" + version + applicationSecret;

            try
            {
                sig = md5(sig);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

            String composedResponse =
                    "api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8")
                            + "&call_id=" + callId + "&method="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8") + "&nonce="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8")
                            + "&session_key="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(sessionKey, "utf-8") + "&v="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8") + "&sig="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(sig, "utf-8");

            response = composedResponse.getBytes("utf-8");
        }

        String authenticationText = "";

        if (response != null)
        {
            authenticationText =
                    Base64.encodeBytes(response, Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
        }

        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query)
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] params = query.split("\\&");

        for (String param : params)
        {
            String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
            map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
        }

        return map;
    }

    private String md5(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(text.getBytes("utf-8"), 0, text.length());
        return convertToHex(md.digest());
    }

    private String convertToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        int len = data.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            int halfByte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0xF;
            int twoHalfs = 0;

            do
            {
                if (0 <= halfByte && halfByte <= 9)
                {
                    buf.append((char) ('0' + halfByte));
                }
                else
                {
                    buf.append((char) ('a' + halfByte - 10));
                }
                halfByte = data[i] & 0xF;
            } while (twoHalfs++ < 1);
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Thank you for you Help :)

Comment: have you got the solution for your quesiton

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create XMPP chat client for facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook)