# How to connect Facebook chat using xmpp,i want to enter username of friends and then chat-showing SASL Authentication failed

Tags: java, android, facebook, xmpp

I am able to connect xmpp for gtalk,but i dont know how to connnect xmpp for facebook chat,i searched lot,and then i wrote some code,its not working too,

Now i am trying like this,user needs to type his userid and pwd and then user has to type his friends username and msg and then chat.

**XMPPClient.java**

```
public class XMPPClient extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private SettingsDialog mDialog;
    private EditText mRecipient;
    private EditText mSendText;
    private ListView mList;
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "onCreate called");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        mRecipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "mRecipient = " + mRecipient);
        mSendText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sendText);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "mSendText = " + mSendText);
        mList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "mList = " + mList);
        setListAdapter();

        // Dialog for getting the xmpp settings
        mDialog = new SettingsDialog(this);

        // Set a listener to show the settings dialog
        Button setup = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.setup);
        setup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        mDialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Set a listener to send a chat text message
        Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String to = mRecipient.getText().toString();
                String text = mSendText.getText().toString();

                Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");
                Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);
                connection.sendPacket(msg);
                messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                messages.add(text);
                setListAdapter();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with the XMPP server
     *
     * @param connection
     */
    public void setConnection
            (XMPPConnection
                    connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody() + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }

    private void setListAdapter
            () {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.multi_line_list_item,
                messages);
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**settings.java**

```
     public class SettingsDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    private XMPPClient xmppClient;


    public SettingsDialog(XMPPClient xmppClient) {
        super(xmppClient);
        this.xmppClient = xmppClient;
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        getWindow().setFlags(4, 4);
        setTitle("XMPP Settings");
        Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String host = getText(R.id.host);
        String port = getText(R.id.port);
        String service = getText(R.id.service);
        String username = getText(R.id.userid);
        String password = getText(R.id.password);

        //GTalk...Host name : talk.google.com       The port number is 5222 service name : gmail.com
        //Yahoo...Host name : iopibm.msg.yahoo.com  The default port is 5061 service name : yahoo.com
        //Facebook Hostname : chat.facebook.com     The port number is 5222  service = chat.facebook.com for authentication SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        try
        {
            SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
            SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
            xmpp.connect();
            xmpp.login("268651109963113", "268651109963113|zq84UUmSj7vh_I8oj7yfGLebKgY", "Application");
        } catch (XMPPException e)
        {
            xmpp.disconnect();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private String getText(int id) {
        EditText widget = (EditText) this.findViewById(id);
        return widget.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

**SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism .java**

```
public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

private static final String NAME = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

private String apiKey = "268651109963113";
private String access_token = "268651109963113|zq84UUmSj7vh_I8oj7yfGLebKgY";

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
    super(saslAuthentication);
}

@Override
protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {

    getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
}

@Override
public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String acces_token)
        throws IOException, XMPPException {
    if (apiKey == null || acces_token == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
    }

    this.access_token = acces_token;
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
    this.hostname = host;

    String[] mechanisms = { NAME };
    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props,
            this);
    authenticate();
}

@Override
public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh)
        throws IOException, XMPPException {
    String[] mechanisms = { NAME };
    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props,
            cbh);
    authenticate();
}

@Override
protected String getName() {
    return NAME;
}

@Override
public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
    byte[] response = null;

    if (challenge != null) {
        String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
        Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

        String version = "1.0";
        String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
        String method = parameters.get("method");

        long callId = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();

        String composedResponse = "api_key="
                + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8") + "&call_id=" + callId
                + "&method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8")
                + "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8")
                + "&access_token="
                + URLEncoder.encode(access_token, "utf-8") + "&v="
                + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");

        response = composedResponse.getBytes("utf-8");
    }

    String authenticationText = "";

    if (response != null) {
        authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response,
                Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
    }

    // Send the authentication to the server
    getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
}

private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] params = query.split("\\&");

    for (String param : params) {
        String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
        map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
    }

    return map;
}
}
```

Now my updated code throwing NPE in these lines

```
Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);
                connection.sendPacket(msg);
```

First it will open the dialog box from there we need to type the userid and pwd and then wants to type the username of friends list and then msg and then click send like this i am trying,,,i am typing the user name correctly too,but its showing NUll ponter exception while clicking send button

Comment: Try to clean your project and if cleaning project doesn't work then just restart your eclipse once and check.

Comment: yup i tried all the ways dude @InnocentKiller and could you check my code is correct or wrong

Comment: Okay, then problem might be you have 2 jar files somewhere that include the same package and classes.

Comment: Do you have any `android_maps_lib` in your project.

Comment: no dude i am having android_support4jar,asmack-2010.04.02.jar,asmack-2010.05.07.jar,asmack-issue15.jar,asmack-jse-buddycloud-2010.12.11.jar,httpclient-4.1.3.jar,httpcore-4.1.4.jar,org.xbill.dns_2.1.6.jar,smack.jar,smackx.jar,smackx-debug.jar,smackx-jingle.jar,xpp3-1.1.4c.jar, i am having these many,if i delete one it showing error shomewhere in the code@InnocentKiller

Comment: Whether this both is needed `asmack-2010.04.02.jar,asmack-2010.05.07.jar`. Because i think you have a some jar files which includes same classes 2 or more times and that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: after deleting these two jar,its showing error in code @InnocentKiller

Comment: not both delete any one, because this both jar looks same to me, so try to delete any one and then try.

Comment: its showing lots of error in r.java and other errors also dude @InnocentKiller can i share my code to u

Comment: @InnocentKiller i remvoed smack.jar from lib folder,so now its not showing that error

Comment: Nice, whether your project is running smoothly or not.

Comment: nope dude,this error only solved Dalvik format failed with error 1,i dont think so my code is correct or wrong for facebook xmpp chat @InnocentKiller

Comment: Okay so can i post this as a answer.

Comment: ya,but i cant accept the answer but surely i will upvote it @InnocentKiller ,because my objective of question is how to connect facebook xmpp chat

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be you have 2 jar files somewhere that include the same package and classes. So i strongly recommend you to check your all jar file's once again and delete anyone which is causing the problem.

Deleting this package from one of the JAR files will solved the problem.

Comment: Dalvik format failed with error 1 this problem solved,thanks for your answer,but how to connect facebook chat using xmpp

Comment: @KarthickM, i don't have any idea about that, really sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official [Facebook Chat API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/), which you need to follow when implementing chat client - to authenticate user you need show him WebView form where he authenticate your application on the Facebook, get authentication token, and **that** token wll be used in X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL mechanism.

Comment: autentical token in the sense are you mentioning apikey and accesstoken

Comment: Please, read full authentication flow description: api key and access token is what you give when connect to facebook, and authentication token is what facebook give to user when he allow your app to access his facebook account.

Comment: ,do you any example or full code of how to connect the facebook xmpp chat

Comment: for login we have to give like this example@gmail.com or example@chatfacebook.com